# Grammar involving braces

Tags: prolog, dcg, left-recursion

I'm trying to solve DCG grammar in prolog and succeeded upto a point, i'm stuck in evaluating the expressions involving braces like these. 
`expr( T, [’(’, 5, +, 4, ’)’, *, 7], []),`

```
expr(Z) --> num(Z).
expr(Z) --> num(X), [+], expr(Y), {Z is X+Y}.
expr(Z) --> num(X), [-], expr(Y), {Z is X-Y}.
expr(Z) --> num(X), [*], expr(Y), {Z is X*Y}.
num(D) --> [D], {number(D)}.

eval(L, V, []) :- expr(V, L, []).
```

Comment: Your grammar doesn't handle operator precedence correctly because it always parses left-to-right. Try parsing `[5, *, 4, +, 7]` and check the resulting value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parsers implemented by Prolog's DCG grammars are recursive-descent LL(*something*) (predictive) grammars. It walks the input from left to right and produces a leftmost derivation as it goes. They're easy to craft but the grammar's must conform to a few restrictions:

**They cannot be left-recursive.** Infinite recursion can/will result. This means that at least one symbol (token) has to be removed from the input stream prior to following a recursive path. Refactoring grammars to remove left-recursion is a fairly mechanical exercise, albeit tedious. See any decent compiler book on how to do that.

**Operator precedence is typically built into the structure of the grammar itself.** Here's BNF notation showing one way of defining a recursive descent grammar for the parsing/evaluation of simple arithmetic expressions:

```
ArithmeticExpression     : AdditiveExpression
                         ;

AdditiveExpression       : MultiplicativeExpression
                         | MultiplicativeExpression '+' AdditiveExpression
                         | MultiplicativeExpression '-' AdditiveExpression
                         ;

MultiplicativeExpression : ExponentialExpression
                         | ExponentialExpression '*' MultiplicativeExpression
                         | ExponentialExpression '/' MultiplicativeExpression
                         | ExponentialExpression '%' MultiplicativeExpression
                         ;

ExponentialExpression    : UnaryExpression
                         | UnaryExpression '^' ExponentialExpression
                         ;

UnaryExpression          : '-' UnaryExpression
                         | AtomicExpression
                         ;

AtomicExpression         : '(' ArithmeticExpression ')'
                         | ['0'..'9']+
                         ;
```

The term at each level of operator precedence is built from expressions of the next higher order of precedence. So an arbitrary arithmetic expression is just a single additive expression.

Each additive expression is 1 or more multiplicative expressions, joined by addition and subtraction operators.

Each multiplicative expression is 1 or more exponential expressions, joined by multiplication, division and remainder operators.

Each exponential expression is a unary expression with an option exponent operator followed by another unary expression.

Each unary expression  is either an atomic expression, or a unary minus followed by another unary expression.

Each atomic expression is either an arbitrary arithmetic expression, enclosed in parentheses, or an unsigned integer token.

Translation of the above into Prolog's DCG syntax should be trivial. How to evaluate the term represented by each clause in the grammar should be self-evident.

Comment: The above syntax is not correct. You cannot parse 1 + 2 + 3 since there is some link between MultiplicativeExpression back to AdditiveExpression missing. So I have to vote you down. So contrary to what your write "Each additive expression is 1 or more multiplicative expressions, joined by addition and subtraction operators." the grammar does not do this. It only covers maximally 1 additional multiplicative expression.

Comment: If you fix the grammar correctly then the phrase "Translation of the above into Prolog's DCG syntax should be trivial." will probably not hold anymore. So that one will have to regress into "Refactoring grammars to remove left-recursion is a fairly mechanical exercise, albeit tedious." which makes your whole post a little inconsistent.

Comment: See my tweaked grammar example, above.

Comment: That comes with a cost: Prolog's DCG syntactic sugar gives you a recursive descent parser for nothing, in Prolog, you're going to have to wire up your packrat parser from scratch. Myself...I'd just use Prolog's built-in operator precedence predicates, define the operators I want and consult the text in. Why do more work than you need to?

Comment: You wrote "in Prolog, you're going to have to wire up your packrat parser from scratch", I dunno, many Prologs have tabling and doing tabling via assert is also not that difficult. You can then combine tabling and DCG. Just idea, have to check the details one time. I mentioned tabling since I wanted to point out that refactoring is not the only way to deal with left recursion, tabling would be another.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the strangest things I observed in the history of Prolog.
Namely that a wrong expression syntax is shown around already for ages.
The wrong syntax is already found in the DEC10 Prolog documentation
and the misfit is seen when we look at a rule:

```
 expr(Z) --> num(X), "/", expr(Y), {Z is X/Y}.
 etc..
```

This makes the division operator xfy, but it should be yfx. Thus with
the above rule an expression 10/2/5 is read as 10/(2/5) and leads to
25 as the result. But in fact the example should be read as (10/2)/5
yielding 1 as the result.

The problem is that the correct syntax would be left recursive.
And DCG do have problems with left recursive rules. The Prolog 
interpreter would just run into an infinite loop for a left 
recursive rules by repeatedly call expr/3:

```
 expr(Z) --> expr(X), "/", num(Y), {Z is X/Y}
 etc..
```

So the solution is to eliminate the left recursion by introducing
an accumulator and additional rules. I don't know whether this
method works in general, but it works for sure in the present case.
So the correct and depth first executable rule would read:

```
 expr(Y) --> num(X), expr_rest(X,Y).

 expr_rest(X,T) --> "/", !, num(Y), {Z is X/Y}, expr_rest(Z,T).
 etc..
 expr_rest(X,X).
```

The above grammar is a little bit a more challenging DCG. It is not
anymore pure Prolog, since it uses the cut (!). But we could
eliminate the cut, for example by a push-back, something along
the following lines. The push-back is again a complicated
matter to explain in a DCG introduction, and we would need to
introduce an stop character at the end of an expression to make
it work:

```
 etc..
 expr_rest(X,X), [C] --> [C], {not_operator(C)}.
```

Or we could neither go into the lengths of the cut or the push-back
and live with it that on backtracking the parser will do additional,
in the present case unnecessary, work. So bottom line is probably, 
although the example is not correct, it is simple enough to explain DCG 
without needing to much advanced stuff of DCG.

Interestinglyg the missing parenthesis syntax is hardly affected by 
the elimination of left recursion. Simply add:

```
 num(X) --> "(", !, expr(X), ")".
```

Oops, a cut again!

Best Regards

Full code can be seen here:
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/05_run/06_bench/09_programs/10_calculator/01_calculator.p.html

P.S.: Instead of eliminating the left recursion, we could also have
worked with some form of tabling.

Comment: btw in swi-prolog 5.8.2 10/2/5 evaluates to 1 and the '/' is listed as yfx

Comment: Yes, as I said, yfx is the correct interpretation and not xfy as the naive DCG would do. Try the naive DCG and tell me what it does.

Comment: naive DCG ->  expr(Z) --> num(X), "/", expr(Y), {Z is X/Y}. ? yes, this returns 25 xd

Comment: Prolog to handle order of execution makes it hard to design a recursion for beginners.

Comment: The given solution makes use of recursion and what has become known as accumulator variables in Prolog. http://www.sju.edu/~jhodgson/ai/accums.html

Answer (score 4):

It just works.  However it is not easier than yacc/bison.

```
%?-eval('11*(7+5-2)^2*(11+8)').
eval(A) :- lex(A,L), evallist(L).

%?-evallist([11,*,'(',7,+,5,-,2,')',^,2,*,'(',11,+,8,')']).
evallist(L) :- e(R,L,[]),write(R),!.

e(N) --> t(N1), erest(N1,N).

erest(N1,N) --> [+], !, t(N2), {N3 is N1+N2}, erest(N3,N);
                [-], !, t(N2), {N3 is N1-N2}, erest(N3,N).
erest(N,N) --> [].

t(N) --> f(N1), trest(N1,N).

trest(N1,N) --> [*], !, f(N2), {N3 is N1*N2}, trest(N3,N);
                [/], !, f(N2), {N3 is N1/N2}, trest(N3,N).
trest(N,N) --> [].

f(N) --> n(N);
     n(N1), [^], f(N2), {N is N1**N2}.

n(N) --> ['('], !, e(N), [')'];
     [-], !, e(N1), {N is -N1};
     num(N). 

num(N) --> [N], {number(N)}.

lex(A,NL) :- 
  atom_chars(A,L), lex0(_,L,NL).

lex0(S,L,NL) :-
  L=[], (number(S), NL=[S], !; NL=[]), !;
  L=[E|R], (d(E,N), (number(S), !; S=0), S1 is S*10+N, lex0(S1, R, NL), !;
     lex0(_,R,NR), (number(S), NL=[S|[E|NR]], !;
        NL=[E|NR])).

d(I,N) :- 
  char_code(I,C), C > 47, C < 58, N is C - 48.
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this clause appears to work: `num(D) --> ['('], expr(D), [')'].`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @vladimir lidovski and based on the BNF notation (and on my needs), I expanded it to also include logical expressions. Here is my code (To see the full interpreter checkout my [git repo](https://github.com/nkatz01/logic-programming-nkatz01)):

```
cond_expre(T) -->  and_expre(E1), or_rest(E1,T).     

or_rest(E1,T) -->  [punct('|'),punct('|')],!, and_expre(E2),   {V  = (\/,E1,E2)}, or_rest(V,T).
or_rest(T,T) --> [].

and_expre(T) --> equality_expre(E1), and_rest(E1,T).
and_rest(E1,T) --> [punct(&),punct(&)], !, equality_expre(E2), {V  = (/\,E1,E2)}, and_rest(V,T).
and_rest(T,T) --> [].

equality_expre(T) -->   relat_expre(E1), equality_rest(E1,T).   
equality_rest(E1,T) --> equality_op(Op) ,!,  relat_expre(E2), {  V=(Op,E1,E2)}, equality_rest(V,T).
equality_rest(T,T) --> [].

relat_expre(T) --> atomic_texpre(E1), relat_rest(E1,T). 
relat_rest(E1,T) -->  relat_op(Op) ,!, atomic_texpre(E2) , { V=(Op,E1,E2) },relat_rest(V,T).
relat_rest(T,T) --> [].

atomic_texpre(T) -->  arith_expre(T); [punct('(')], !, cond_expre(T), [punct(')')]      .
arith_expre(V) --> expre(V).



equality_op(==)         --> [punct(=),punct(=)]. 
equality_op(\=)        --> [punct(!),punct(=)]. 
relat_op(>=)        --> [punct(>),punct(=)]. 
relat_op(>)         --> [punct(>)]. 
relat_op('=<')        -->  [punct(<),punct(=)]. 
relat_op(<)         --> [punct(<)]. 



expre(N) --> multiplicative(N1), additive_rest(N1,N).

additive_rest(N1,N) --> [punct('+')], !, multiplicative(N2), {N3 = (+,N1,N2)}, additive_rest(N3,N);  
                        [punct('-')], !, multiplicative(N2), {N3 = (-,N1,N2)}, additive_rest(N3,N).
additive_rest(N,N) --> [].

multiplicative(N) --> atomic(N1), multiplicative_rest(N1,N).
multiplicative_rest(N1,N) --> [punct('*')], !, atomic(N2), {N3 = (*,N1,N2)}, multiplicative_rest(N3,N);
                                [punct('/')], !, atomic(N2), {N3 = (/,N1,N2)}, multiplicative_rest(N3,N);   
                                [punct('%')], !, atomic(N2), {N3 = (mod,N1,N2)}, multiplicative_rest(N3,N).
multiplicative_rest(N,N) --> [].

atomic(N) --> [punct('(')], !, expre(N), [punct(')')];  num(N). 
num(N) --> pl_constant(N).

pl_constant(num(N))     --> pl_integer(N), !.
pl_constant(id(X))       --> identifier(X), {call(id(X,_)) }. %Not sure if I remember what it does but I think, the right most call I wrote to assure that the variable is already registered in the cache so that a value can later be retrieved from it  

pl_integer(X)              --> [number(X)]. %the value on the right works together with a tokenizer library ->  :- use_module(library(tokenize)). It's basically a token labled as a number. Same with the next line.
identifier(X)              --> [word(X)].
```